# Predis Alias Sharding

Tags: php, redis, predis

I'm trying to use Predis sharding by alias, as [described here](https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/36#issuecomment-12193172).  My code is basically identical, but I'm only returning empty arrays.  Do my hash keys need {} around them? (EDIT: Nope, just tried it)

```
  $api->get("/test", function () {

    $servers = [
      ["alias" => "metadata", "port" => 6380],
      ["alias" => "relations", "port" => 6381],
      ["alias" => "dim_provider", "port" => 6382],
      ["alias" => "dim_revctrcode", "port" => 6383],
      ["alias" => "dim_enccode", "port" => 6384],
      ["alias" => "dim_pos", "port" => 6385]
    ];

    $options = [

      "nodehash" => function ($connection) { return $connection->getParameters()->alias; },

      "cluster" => function ($options) {
        $replicas = Predis\Cluster\Distribution\HashRing::DEFAULT_REPLICAS;
        $hashring = new Predis\Cluster\Distribution\HashRing($replicas, $options->nodehash);
        $cluster = new Predis\Connection\PredisCluster($hashring);

        return $cluster;
      }
    ];

    $redis = new Predis\Client($servers, $options);

    try {
      $test = $redis->scard("dim_provider");
      print_r($test);  // Prints 0 for scard or empty Array for hgetall
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      print $e->getMessage();
    }

    $redis = new Predis\Client(["port" => 6382]);
    $test = $redis->scard("dim_provider");
    print_r($test);  // Works.
  });
```

EDIT: It also works if I only put one server in the `$servers` array.  So it seems the hashing is not working right. When I throw some echos in front of the return value in `nodehash` I can see that it's returning the alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a `dim_provider` **alias** to a Redis connection and trying to get a **key** named `dim_provider` from a server are two different things.

In your script you are trying to set up a cluster of Redis instances using connection aliases (instead of the usual `ip:port` pairs) to calculate the distribution of your keyspace among multiple Redis servers acting as your [data shards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29). Using this setup, the key `dim_provider` is sharded accordingly to the underlying distribution algorithm and could be stored on any of the 6 servers composing your cluster and defined in the `$servers` array.

Comment: Thanks. Clearly I'm misunderstanding alias sharding.  My goal is to host each dimension on a separate shard.  Say I have a set called `dim_provider` coupled with hashes called `dim_provider:id` The API will connect to the redis cluster and know which server to go to based on the key it needs.  Would I need to write my own distribution strategy?  Probably would just be easier to map key: port pairs within my PHP script.

Comment: Usually when using client-side sharding you don't care which server keys are being stored in, ideally the keyspace is evenly distributed among your Redis instances. You can indeed balance the load on each server by assigning a `weight` parameter or use key tags to ensure that certain groups of keys are stored on the same shard by calculating the hash only on the portion of a key wrapped in `{}`, but you won't be able to enforce the target server based on the key.

Comment: In a sense your use case can be seen as a very specialized kind of partitioning but it doesn't play well with the common strategies used to distribute keys with client-side sharding. Considering what you are trying to achieve I'd just use multiple instances of `Predis\Client`, one for each server, but nothing stops you from writing your own cluster backend class by implementing `Predis\Connection\ClusterConnectionInterface` that analyzes each Redis command for its keys to decide which server should be used. Customization is one of the selling points of Predis after all.

Comment: Agreed, and thanks again for the clarification and this awesome library.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add how trivially easy it was to implement my clustering strategy once nrk got me on the right track. This is a really well-written library.

```
 $api->get("/test", function () {

    Class KeyCluster extends Predis\Connection\PredisCluster {

      public function __construct() {
        $this->pool = Array();
      }

      public function add (Predis\Connection\SingleConnectionInterface $connection) {
        $parameters = $connection->getParameters();
        if (isset($parameters->table)) {
            $this->pool[$parameters->table] = $connection;
        } else {
            $this->pool[] = $connection;
        }
      }

      public function getConnection (Command\CommandInterface $command) {
        $key = $command->getArgument(0);
        $table = explode(":", $key)[0];
        return isset($this->pool[$table]) ? $this->pool[$table] : null;
      }
    }

    $redis = new Predis\Client([
      "tcp://127.0.0.1:6382?table=dim_provider",
      "tcp://127.0.0.1:6383?table=dim_pos"
    ],[
      "cluster" => new KeyCluster
    ]);

    $result = $redis->scard("dim_provider");
    print_r($result);
  });
```

Comment: Your approach is basically the same I had in mind, but my advice is that you should really create your cluster class by implementing `Predis\Connection\ClusterConnectionInterface` instead of extending `Predis\Connection\PredisCluster`. Copying only the relevant parts of code from `Predis\Connection\PredisCluster` for your class is fine, it's just that there's a lot of stuff in the parent class that you don't need or doesn't even make sense in your case. Indeed you'll end up writing a bit more code, but that's something you write only once to obtain a cleaner solution.

Comment: That actually is what I ended up doing. There wasn't *too* much extra in there, but it does remove a dependency and allows for further customized behavior.